# UITextView() cannot be defined as nil?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I am trying to implement a method to move the scrollview so the textview isn't blocked by the keyboard.
As a part of the standard code, the UITextView needs to be set to nil but it's not working.

I first declared

```
var activeTextView = UITextView()
```

then

```
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(textView: UITextView) {
    self.activeTextView = nil
    scrollView.scrollEnabled = false
}
```

xcode shows an error saying, UITextView does not conform to NilLiteralConvertible.
Why?

Comment: Don't you need to declare your text view as `activeTextView?` to allow it to be nil?

Comment: You need activeTextView to be optional to accept nil values: `var activeTextView:UITextView? = UITextView()`

Comment: how do I get activeTextView.frame after setting it to "UITextView?" ? If I force unwrap the app crashes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is not correct! It is not because it needs to be a `UIView`. Both `UITextView` and UITextField are subclasses of UIView, and you are using the wrong one.

You want either this from the textFieldDelegate:

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField)
```

https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/index.html

or this from the textViewDelegate

```
func textViewDidEndEditing(textView: UITextView)
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html

The reason yours worked with UIView is because both subclass it, but that does not make it correct!

Comment: how do I get activeTextView.frame after setting it to
"UITextView?" ? If I force unwrap the app crashes

Comment: Have it as an optional :) Do you understand how to do that?

Comment: so i tried self.activeTextView!.frame , which kinda works but later crashes. Also tried self.activeText?.frame which just crashes straight away :( might have to post a separate question with the full code

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your Question right, you just need to declear your TextView as an optional, because in Swift you cant set an non optional Object to nil.

```
var activeTextView: UITextView?
```

Should solve your Problem.

The Questionmark will declear it as an optional and only an optional could be nil.